# Can not add a second foreign key when creating table

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I am creating a table with 2 foreign keys
but whenever I have the second key, it will return an error:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    stars INT,
    business_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(business_id) REFERENCES businesses(id),
    user_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

It will throw syntax error near `user_id`, and if I put `business_id` after `user_id`, it will throw syntax error near `business_id`...

And if I only put one foreign key there, it will just create the table, tried several times. What's the problem here?
`users` and `businesses` are two tables, I'm creating a junction table for them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix column definition with constraint definition. Columns first, constraints after:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    stars INT,
    business_id INT,
    user_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(business_id) REFERENCES businesses(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```